# FabricJS Polygon height width not increasing object size but bounding box

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I am trying to increase size of polygon object but instead of increasing object size it is only increasing padding between object and bounding boxes.

[Please see results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3o0fo.png)

Here is my code:

```
let newObject = window.saveCoordinates;

let objectWidth = fabric.util.parseUnit(params.width + 'in');
let objectHeight = fabric.util.parseUnit(params.length + 'in');

console.log(objectWidth, objectHeight)
var polygon = new fabric.Polygon(newObject, {
    left: 100,
    top: 100,
    width: objectWidth,
    height: objectHeight,
    scaleX: 1,
    scaleY: 1,
    originX: 0,
    originY: 0,
});

polygon.setCoords();
canvas.add(polygon);
canvas.renderAll();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For polygons, paths and images you want to use the `scaleX` and `scaleY` properties to set the size. You can either set these values directly, or use the `scaleToWidth()` or `scaleToHeight()` methods to make the scale values calculate proportionately to fit your intended dimensions.

If you add a working code snippet to your question I can update this answer with an example.

Comment: Thanks i just use scaleToWidth() its working fine now. thanks for your support..
i don't know who down vote my question please upvote thanks.